# How do you fill a small div entirely with a background image in css?

Tags: html, css

So I got a problem. For school I have an asignment for making a simple website, and one of the  problems I've got is that a big picture won't fit in a small div using css, here's my css:

```
#face{height:100%;width:80%;background-image:url('./pictures/face.jpg');float:left;}
```

and here's my html

```
<div id='face'>          </div>
```

I know how to fix this problem in html, but not in css, can someone help me?

Kind regards,

A 15 year old student

Answer (score 0):

You have given your div a percentage as height and width, but of what?

Your body needs to have a size for the div to relate to.

http://jsfiddle.net/q42Zq/

```
body {
    height:500px;
    width:900px;
}
```

Comment: I have a div inside a div wich holds 3 other divs and those 3 are being held by a few more divs.

Comment: Can you post all of your relevant code then? put it on jsfiddle.net and post a link

Answer (score 0):

try background-size: 100%;

this should stretch the background to cover the entire div.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

working example with one image:   http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gJCuv

CSS:

```
 div{
```

width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:3px solid blue;
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRwR8YYfYmRSuv-tQgN-2yMyIgKQTCY2gSeXKHFKSxRlXZxsi8K);
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

Comment: I've tried, but it didn't work, maybe it's a problem that I used so many divs? jsfiddle.net/mfLwb

Comment: You can debug your CSS in browser right click on the div  inspect element